# How to deploy templates to different schema databases?

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

I have staging and final databases, both currently sharing a schemas database. We're using TDE, where some templates apply to staging and some to final.

Can ml-gradle deploy some templates to one schemas database and others to a second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. My directory structure needs to be like this:

```
-- src
  -- main
    -- ml-config
      -- databases
        -- schemas-db-1
          -- schemas
            -- tde
              -- template-a.xml
        -- schemas-db-2
          -- schemas
            -- tde
              -- template-b.xml
```

... where `schemas-db-1` is the name of the first schemas database. Looks like this requires ml-gradle 3.11.0 or higher (didn't work in 3.9.0).

Comment: Add see https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/DHF-Integration for instructions on how to force DHF to use a different version of ml-gradle.